# How to get 403 access denied with spring security?

Tags: spring-security, http-status-code-403

I never get 403, it always redirects me to root url or I can specify access denied page which is depreciated. Which is ok, but still why?  I want to undertsand its behavior why other people here get this exception?

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
    <security:form-login login-processing-url="/static/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t"  default-target-url="/home"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/home/try" access="hasRole('ROLE_EDITOR')"/>

</security:http>
```

And what is the benefit of using access-denied-handler?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is uses “access-denied-handler‘ tag, and put your 403 page in “error-page” attribute.
You can reference this tutorial:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/customize-http-403-access-denied-page-in-spring-security/